# Images of regular maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need help in verifying my solution on two questions about the images of certain regular maps.

$1)$ Consider a regular function $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. I want to describe the image $\mbox{Im}(g).$ First, we know that $g$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. If $g$ is a constant $c\in\mathbb{C}$ then, of course, $\mbox{Im}(g)=\{c\}.$ Otherwise, by fundamental theorem of algebra, $\mbox{Im}(g)=\mathbb{C}$: for $y\in \mathbb{C} \ $, $  g-y \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and hence has a root.

$2)$ Here, my goal is to understand whether the image of a regular map $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ can be equal to the affine variety $V(xy):=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{C}^2:ab=0\}\subset \mathbb{C}^2$. I think this is not possible; I have tried to show $\mbox{Im}(f)\neq V(xy).$ Since $f$ is regular, $f=(f_1,f_2)$ where $f_i:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ are regular functions. We know each of $f_i$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Suppose $\mbox{Im}(f)\subseteq V(xy).$ This means that given an arbitrary $p\in\mathbb{C}^2$ and $f(p)=(f_1(p),f_2(p))\in \mbox{Im}(f)$, we have $f_1(p)\cdot f_2(p)=0$. Then $f_1 \equiv 0$ or $f_2\equiv 0$ given that $\mathbb{C}$ is an integral domain and $p$ is arbitrary. So we have $f=(0,f_2)$ or $f=(f_1,0).$ If $f_i$ are constant polynomials, then $V(xy)=V(x) \cup V(y) \not\subseteq \mbox{Im}(f).$ To summarize, we see that the inclusion $\mbox{Im}(f)\subseteq V(xy)$ puts a restriction that $f=(0,f_2)$ or $f=(f_1,0).$ Furthermore, for $\mbox{Im}(f)\supseteq V(xy)$ to be true, it is necessary that we have $f_i$ as non-constant polynomials. However, it is *not* a sufficient condition as we show now. To this end, we recall that a complex non-constant bivariate polynomial has infinitely many zeroes, in particular it has a root. So $f_i(\mathbb{C}^2)=\mathbb{C}$, as $f_i$'s are non-constant. Suppose $f=(f_1,0)$. But clearly 
$$
V(xy)=V(x)\cup V(y) \not\subseteq (\mathbb{C},0)=(f_1(\mathbb{C}^2),0)=\mbox{Im}(f).
$$
Similarly, we show the claim for $f=(0,f_2)$. Could someone check if what I have done is correct? Is there a nicer way to do the second problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1, your reasoning is correct.

For Q2, you can use the concept of [irreducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_component). In particular, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is irreducible in the Zariski topology. Since images of irreducible spaces under continuous maps are irreducible, regular maps are Zariski-continuous, and $V(xy)$ is reducible as $V(x) \cup V(y)$, your conclusion is correct.